# Button event registers only every other click

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling, windows-embedded-compact

I created a standard button using Expression Blend 3 and tied this into an event handler for turning on an led. I also have a similar button for turning off the led. I am passing this event between subprojects (front end to back end) using windows `CreateEvent()` and `SetEvent()`.

The issue im running into is that i have to press the button twice for the back end to register the event. Each click will be registered by the front end and the `SetEvent()` function will be executed, but only on the second pass will it be picked up in the back end.

Front end implementation:

```
HRESULT MainPage::Disable_Alarm_Click (IXRDependencyObject* pSender, XRMouseButtonEventArgs* pArgs)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_NOTIMPL;

    if ((NULL == pSender) || (NULL == pArgs))
    {
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    SetEvent(s_hEvent[19]); //Notify back end that event occured

return hr;
}
```

Back end event implementation:

```
m_hEvents[ALARM_DISABLE_1] = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, ALARM_DISABLE_EVENT);
if(m_hEvents[ALARM_DISABLE_1] == NULL)
{
    return;
}
```

Back end event scanning:

```
case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + ALARM_DISABLE_1:
        //Do stuff 
        //I put a breakpoint here but it does not hit it until second pass
            break;
```

To clarify the `case`, i have a switch-case infinite loop containing the list of all events pertaining to the back end and this works without issue since the other events are registered every time they occur.

Im not sure if i am doing something wrong in my code. It seems fairly straightforward as far as the coding is concerned. Is this just a bug with the Windows function?

I've tried stepping through the code to see what is going on and it always hits my `SetEvent` function so I havent found any issues with my code. It just seems that the `SetEvent` does not set the event object name every time.

Comment: What does your `WaitForMultipleObjects` call look like?

Comment: `DWORD retval = WaitForMultipleObjects(Number_Of_Events, pEventListener->m_hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE);` where `Number_Of_Events` is 17, it waits for all of the threads, and `m_hEvents` is the handles of the events. Then i pass `retval` to my `switch` statement.

Comment: Using events for signaling is very brittle.  When do you call ResetEvent()?  Are you sure you do that only after the other process has seen it?  Use a named pipe or socket instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I do not call `ResetEvent()` because, my understanding of the description of `CreateEvent()` led me to believe this is automatically handled in the process. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the description of the event object name field. Maybe i misinterpreted it.

Also, i dont think i can use pipes/socket since this is a windows embedded compact application. Im not an expert on this OS so i may be wrong.